# Right-justified offset alignment of overlays using GeometryReader

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to right-align several overlays but am unable to figure out how to do this.

What I have here is a `VStack` of 2 images on the right side of the screen, and I want to display an overlay text label for each image, to the left of the image, but right-aligned with the other labels, like so:

```
      A LABEL  A
ANOTHER LABEL  B
```

The code below displays the labels center aligned, like so:

```
   A LABEL     A
ANOTHER LABEL  B
```

```
struct TestOverlayOffset : View {
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "a.circle").font(.title)
                    .overlay(labelOnTheLeft("A LABEL"))
                Image(systemName: "b.circle").font(.title)
                    .overlay(labelOnTheLeft("ANOTHER LABEL"))
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.gray)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
    
    func labelOnTheLeft(_ text: String) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Text(text)
                .fixedSize()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .offset(x: -128 - proxy.size.width/2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible solution (with smallest changes and removed hardcoding).

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
func labelOnTheLeft(_ text: String) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Text(text)
            .fixedSize()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .padding(.trailing)
            .offset(x: -proxy.size.width)
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, alignment: .trailing)
    }
}
```